# Seaport and Wyvern for proxy contracts

Tags: opensea

I saw that open sea move to Seaport protocol from Wyvern but from what I see for proxy contract and isApprovedForAll function ppl still use Wyvern, so I guess that part is not migrated and wasnt ment to move? I dont see anything changed from their docs, still wyvern referenced there.